# Technology used in LED stumps and bails in WorldCup-2015?

Tags: led

I just know that when the bails are taken off from the stumps the LEDs will glow.Could somebody explain how exactly the concept works in case of LED stumps and bails which have been used in the World-Cup tournament Or provide a link which explains this.

The image below depicts the terms used in the title of the question.
[image]

**EDIT (For those who don't know Cricket):**

Objective of the LEDs are to detect whenever Bails (Horizontal sticks) are moved away from Stumps (The vertical wooden sticks) or not. 
In game, A player will throw "Ball" from a distance to dislocate Bails from Stumps. If he succeeds, he gets a point. To detect easily, Cricket Organizers added LEDs to bails.
Video: https://youtu.be/dumkGXj0F5E

This is picture of a real stumps and bails.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to what  you are talking about? I doubt many people are familiar with this.

Comment: Hello user36129, I just got to hear this from one of the conversation.Even i am sure of the technology that they have made use of.

Comment: I have no way of knowing, but I suspect magnetic reed switches, or maybe Hall effect devices.

Comment: Could you re-write it in something that approximates everyday English? This is not a soccer forum. We shouldn't need to look up what bails and stumps are, and why would there be any LEDs involved. You have to do some more work on making this question useful to anyone besides yourself.

Comment: Kuba, I hope its quite clear now.

Comment: @Durgaprasad - I don't have **any** idea still.... Do they.... throw the ball at the vertical sticks? Is the goal to knock the thingies on the top off the sticks? Do the LEDs in question just show where vertically the ball(?) struck the stick thing, or does it show the exact location on the surface (that'd be a lot harder).

Comment: Yes.But the point to be noted here is that "LEDs glow only  when the bails are off from the stumps"!

Comment: It is not only when the bails are off the stumps. If you have bails in your hand then also it will glow. It should be based on some magnetic switch, may be hall or reed. As suggested by Scott Seidman

Comment: @AKR, To the best of knowledge i understand that the LEDs glow only when they are "completely dislodged" from the stumps but not when you have them in your hands. May be the below reference would help!  http://www.rediff.com/cricket/report/slide-show-1-world-t20-led-stumps-and-bails-in-t20-cricket-10-things-you-must-know/20140401.htm#4

Comment: @Durgaprasad, Check the third image of the link you have shared.

Comment: @AKR, You have mistaken the image, this is not to indicate that the LEDs will glow when you have them in your hands.That is just to show that when the bails are dislodged the LEDs glow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a [Cricket Australia](http://www.cricket.com.au/news/josh-hazlewood-hits-stumps-but-they-stay-on-pakistan-world-cup-quarter-final-adelaide/2015-03-20) article that says "The ICC approved the use of the zing bails for international cricket in July 2013". Zings International is a company based in Port Adelaide, Australia and it appears the system was intvented by one of their directors Bronte Eckermann. Doing a patent search on his name the following appears to be the relevant patent:

[System for indicating movement of an article from one position or orientation to another position or orientation](http://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2011044642) that contains the following drawings that is probably the most interesting one:

[image]

The patent leaves open a fair few possibilities for different technologies but the preferred embodiment and the one shown above is based on measuring inductance. The parts maked 44 and 48 are inductors and from the patent:

> With the inductors 44 and 48 in the circuit as shown, the LED's have higher resistance than the inductor coils which have much lower resistance. When the circuit is initially powered the LED's glow. When the circuit is opened, the lights shine very brightly and then quickly go out. This is due to the inductors initially providing a high resistance until a magnetic field is built up at which time the inductors provide less resistance taking current away from the lights which travels through the inductors which by now are low resistance.
>
> When current first starts flowing in the inductor coils, the coils build up a magnetic field. While the magnetic field is building, the coils inhibit the flow of current. Once the magnetic field is built up, current can flow normally through the wire. This is typical inductor operation. The present invention employs an inductive loop including an inductive sensor to detect any change of inductance. When a change of inductance is detected, the LED light triggers.
>
> Each bail has an inductive loop in each arm. A metal pellet in each bail when the bail moves causes a change in inductance, triggering the indicating light. When the stump is placed under the inductive loops in the bails, the bail senses the inductance and monitors the inductance regularly. When the metal saddle in the stump is moved away from the inductive loops, such as by removal of the bails, the bail senses a change in inductance and the LEDs flash for a few seconds and then preferably turn off to save power.

The patent is a relatively recent one filed in 2010 and no doubt some improvements have been made, for example the above seems based on a simple analog circuit whereas their web page describes the bails as having a microprocessor. So it's hard to know exactly what technology they currently use but that system seems to have been the initial method for the bails. The patent doesn't seem to include details on the operation of the stumps and I couldn't find any related patents.

Comment: Can you specify which metal pellet are you talking about? If it is 53 and 54(in the fig) then I assume that the pellet movement cannot be expected here since they are relatively still with the inductor.

Answer (score -1):

Tactile sensors are used, 
these are pressure sensors.
5 sensors are used, two in bails, three in the top of stumps.